# Convert Value to 32-bit values

Tags: python

I have a table Widget and user give a number in table, so when I get this value I want to convert 32 bit hex value.

For example user enter number 10, I need to convert this number

Firstly 0x000A (it need to be hex)

And split like this myList = [0x0,0x0,0x0,0xA]

I tried with below command

```
myNum = 10
value = '0x{0:04X}'.format(myNum)
print(value)
print(list(struct.pack('<H',value)))
```

I get `struct.error: required argument is not an integer`
'0x{0:04X}'.format(myNum) value return string so I couldnt split this value correctly.

I expect this value [0x0,0x0,0x0,0xA]

How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the *result you expect*?

Comment: I expect list array like this : [0x0,0x0,0x0,0xA] . I said in my topic

Comment: That is not an array, that is a list. But OK, then what is the point of `myHex`?

Comment: I dont understand your question because I explain my problem. I need to convert 10 to 4 byte hex value. Why you stack for the myHex ?

Comment: **what do you mean by hex value**? You understand `[0x0,0x0,0x0,0xA] ` is a list with 4 int objects, it is **exactly** the same as `[0, 0, 0, 10]`

Comment: doesnt metter, I need to convert 10 to [0,0,0,10] or [0x0, 0x0,0x0,0xA] value, they are same. But my question is how to convert.

Comment: I don't know why you are using `"<H"` as a format string, that is a little endian unsigned short, it *seems* like you want: `list(struct.pack('>I', num))`, i.e., a big endian unsigned 32 bit int where `num == 10`

Comment: Or, without using `struct`, just `list(num.to_bytes(4, 'big'))` You keep mentioning "hex" but it is totally unclear what you expect or what your result has to do with "hex". You just want to work wiht `num`, `value` (what you were previously calling `myHex` doesn't seem to be related to anything, because that is simply a string representation of a hexadecimal number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do a strut.pack on a string.  It takes integers (as the error describes) and returns a byte string, which you can turn into a list.

```
import struct

myNum = 10
myHex = '0x{0:04X}'.format(myNum)
print(myHex)
mylist = list(struct.pack('>I',myNum))
print(mylist)
print(list(map(hex, mylist)))
```

The last line prints them as hex, but they are not integers, they are strings. And you are trying to use little endian in your code, but the expected output is in Big.